# RMAN connecting to wrong target

Tags: oracle-11g, rman

When I run `rman target / @mydb nocatalog cmdfile=%commands% msglog=%logfile%`, I see `connected to target database: OTHERDB (DBID=3786352837, not open)`.

Comment: What does your tnsnames file contain?

Comment: It contains details about 3 databases on the machine, including "mydb."

Comment: Oracle's vendor system including program licensing and certification process is not conducive to its constituents participating in cooperative communities like this one. (I am Oracle certified but chose to walk away from that world.) Could you please expound your question with some more details and let us know if that edit indicates that you solved the problem or is just relevant data?

Comment: @caleb Info in my edit seemed to do the trick. I did not find it in the Interwebs, rather a DBA friend helped me.

Comment: Someone chose to down-vote the question without explaining why. Weak. IMHO, the question does not need elaboration. Pretty cut & dry.

Answer (score 0):

Setting environment variable ORACLE_DB to the target database helps the cause.

```
   Set ORACLE_SID=mydb
```

StackOverflow and ServerFault seem to suffer from lack of Oracle expertise. Weak.

Comment: You should probably change "helps the cause" to "fixes the problem" to be clear. The first really doesn't indicate that this is the right solution. Also if you think SO/SF are weak in this area how about sticking around and answering some people's questions!

Comment: @caleb Please. My statement was a sincere observation after posting about 4 Oracle related questions, without getting relevant hints/answers. Again, I am no Oracle expert to help others.

Comment: as far as I can tell, unfortunately Oracle DBA's and developers all seem to have their own cliques and communites that they hang out in, and it's difficult to leverage them out of there. It's certainly somewhere that we could try to target for new users though.